# Differences in answers between Python and Fortran

Tags: python, fortran

I am translating a piece of Fortran code into Python and am testing my code with a certain test case.

All the results differ with 0.04% compared to the Fortran results. This is a very small difference and I am not sure if I can almost see this as machine zero or if there are mistakes in my Python implementation.

What is odd is that all the values differ with exactly 0.04...%  from the Fortran results.

Comment: Is the Fortran code single or double-precision floating-point arithmetic (REAL*4 vs REAL*8 or kind=4 vs kind=8, etc)?

Comment: I believe it is double precision!

Comment: It would help to know for sure. If one of them is single and the other is double, then a difference of $4 \times 10^{-4}$ is plausible for calculations which should only be accurate to 6 digits. It might a bit on the high side for single, but there might be an argument. There's much less argument to be made if this is all double-precision.

Comment: The description given with the code is "... is intended to be operated in double precision (64 bit arithmetic).
For simplicity, this is specified by the appropriate compiler flags rather 
than in the code." So I am assuming it is all double precision. In Python I am using the default float types, I believe they will also be double precision?

Comment: How did you compile the Fortran? Did you use `-r8` or something similar to force it to make REAL into 64 bits?

Comment: Yes the compiler flags are '-O -fdefault-real-8 -fdollar-ok', and not sure if its relevant but I used Cygwin's gfortran compiler.

Comment: Then you probably have a bug.

Comment: Ok, thanks Bill. I will commence the debugging (-: Although it is strange that all the values are out by approximately the exact same very small amount.

Comment: What happens when compare partial results? This way you might be able to debug what part of the code (either FORTRAN or Python) is causing the difference.

Comment: Also make sure that you didn't make the classical "index shift by one" error which is often made when translating from Fortran to other languages, and which in some cases may only slightly distort your results.

Comment: In case Cygwin supports bounds checking, make sure to use it. In gfortran it's included in `-fcheck=all`.

Comment: Another thing to look at is how you define your variables.